# Can't create a new user using External Authentication Provider in Web API (Visual Studio 2013 Update 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authentication, asp.net-web-api

**PROBLEM:**

I'm trying to make external authentication work with default Web API template project. I used the following instructions to add support for external authentication services (FB/Google/Microsoft): http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

Just for the record, I was able to make external authentication work with default SPA template project.
Also, new local user creation works fine.

The problem appeared once I tried to use my client app (WPF-based) to register user using external provider (e.g., FB).

For the record, I used these two articles as the starting point: http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/26/dissecting-the-web-api-individual-accounts-templatepart-3-external-accounts/ and thread #21065648 here at Stack Overflow.
They really helped me to understand the entire logic.

here's the short overview of the steps I've done:
two windows, main and the one for external authentication provider, with embedded WebBrowser
the flow:
2.1. user opens an app, main window appears
2.2. user clicks on a button to get the list of all supported external authentication providers,
and here's what happens in the code:

```
            var client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage loginResponse = await client.GetAsync("api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true");
            if (loginResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
            var externalLoginProviders = await loginResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<AuthenticationProvider>>();

            // cleaning resources
            client.Dispose();
            loginResponse.Dispose();

            // obtained data is sent to UI
```

This leads to the list of External Authentication Providers, with name, url, and state. URL is relative, and is used as the redirect to the actual provider (e.g., FB, or Google).

2.3. As soon as the list with external authentication providers is populated, user can enter his/her email, and click on the "Login" button, which will lead to the following:

In second window, with embedded WebBrowser, the latter is Navigated to the provided URL obtained in the previous step. If user logs successfully into the selected provider (e.g., Facebook), and agrees to give my app (Facebook app) necessary permissions (profile), user is navigated back to our website, in the form:

```
            (our base url) /#access_token=XXX&token_type=bearer&expires=YYY
```

This address is then parsed and address params (token, etc.) are saved in the structured form for later use.

Right after that I go to *api/UserInfo* to understand if user already logged on with this external authentication provider or not:

```
            var client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // setting Bearer Token obtained from Auth provider
            client.SetBearerToken(result.AccessToken);

            // calling /api/Account/UserInfo
            var userInfoResponse = await client.GetAsync("api/Account/UserInfo");
            var userInfoMessage = userInfoResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            var userInfo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(userInfoMessage);

            // cleaning resources
            client.Dispose();
            userInfoResponse.Dispose();

            if (userInfo.hasRegistered == true)
            {
                // going to login
            }
```

Right after that, assuming that our user didn't create a user based on his/her login with the given external authentication provider (e.g., FB), yet, we do the following:

```
            var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            data.Add("Email", this.externalUserEmailTextBox.Text);

            var registerExternalUrl = new Uri(string.Concat(baseAddress, @"api/Account/RegisterExternal"));

            var client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);

            // setting Bearer Token obtained from External Authentication provider
            client.SetBearerToken(result.AccessToken);

            var response = client.PostAsync(registerExternalUrl.ToString(), new FormUrlEncodedContent(data)).Result;
```

At this point, user should be created (I have zero changes on the service side apart of uncommenting provider's app id and app secret lines in Startup.Auth.cs).

Unfortunately, this doesn't happen at all. Instead, I get "Internal Server Error" which means that this line,

```
            var info = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

brings null, and so system fails to Authentication correctly with the provided Bearer Token.

I can't understand why. It seems that something is broken in the framework, or I'm doing something wrong...

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @berhir, here's the solution:

1. In MainWindow.xaml.cs, define cookieContainer

   ```
           CookieContainer cookieContainer;
   ```
2. In MainWindow_Loaded event handler, instantiate it:

   ```
           // we create new cookie container
           cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
   ```
3. As soon as user asks app to show all external login providers, instantiate HttpClient using suggested code by @berhir:

   ```
           using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
           using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
           {
               // send request
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

               HttpResponseMessage loginResponse = await client.GetAsync("api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true");
   ```
4. As soon as list of external auth providers is obtained, the next step is to show second window, with embedded WebBrowser. There, you'll have to declare two WinAPI calls for cookies:

   ```
           [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
           public static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lbszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);

           [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
           public static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string url, string cookieName, StringBuilder cookieData, ref int size, Int32 dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved); 

           // and

           private const Int32 InternetCookieHttponly = 0x2000;

           /// <summary>
           /// Gets the URI cookie container.
           /// </summary>
           /// <param name="uri">The URI.</param>
           /// <returns></returns>
           public static CookieContainer GetUriCookieContainer(Uri uri)
           {
               CookieContainer cookies = null;
               // Determine the size of the cookie
               int datasize = 8192 * 16;
               StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
               if (!InternetGetCookieEx(uri.ToString(), null, cookieData, ref datasize, InternetCookieHttponly, IntPtr.Zero))
               {
                   if (datasize < 0)
                   return null;
                   // Allocate stringbuilder large enough to hold the cookie
                   cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
                   if (!InternetGetCookieEx(uri.ToString(), null, cookieData, ref datasize, InternetCookieHttponly, IntPtr.Zero))
                       return null;
               }
               if (cookieData.Length > 0)
               {
                   cookies = new CookieContainer();
                   cookies.SetCookies(uri, cookieData.ToString().Replace(';', ','));
               }
               return cookies;
           }
   ```
5. This window with embedded browser is instantiated, and constructor accepts several params, including start URL (to external auth provider), end URL (resulting with "#access_token=..." or "error...", callback, and, even more important, with the original cookieContainer. We use *InternetSetCookie* WinAPI method to pass that original cookieContainer to WebBrowser's session:

   ```
       // set cookies
       var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(baseAddress).OfType<Cookie>().ToList();
       foreach (var cookie in cookies)
       {
           InternetSetCookie(startUrl, cookie.Name, cookie.Value); 
       }
   ```
6. So, once user succeeds with signing into the selected external auth provider (e.g., Facebook), updated cookieContainer (which includes cookies set in the first HttpClient call, as well as right within WebBrowser right after signing in to external auth provider) obtained using *InternetGetCookieEx* WinAPI call, is sent back to MainWindow.xaml.cs via callback:

   ```
           if (this.callback != null)
           {
               var cookies = GetUriCookieContainer(e.Uri);

               this.callback(new AuthResult(e.Uri, this.providerName, cookies));
           }
   ```
7. There, we issue two new requests, to *api/Account/UserInfo*, and then to *api/Account/RegisterExternal*:

   ```
           this.cookieContainer = result.CookieContainer; // where result is AuthResult containing the cookies obtained from WebBrowser's session

           using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
           using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
           {
               // send request
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

               // setting Bearer Token obtained from Auth provider
               client.SetBearerToken(result.AccessToken);

               // calling /api/Account/UserInfo
               var userInfoResponse = await client.GetAsync("api/Account/UserInfo");

               var userInfo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(userInfoMessage);

           if (userInfo.hasRegistered == false)
           {
               var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
               data.Add("Email", this.externalUserEmailTextBox.Text);

               var registerExternalUrl = new Uri(string.Concat(baseAddress, @"api/Account/RegisterExternal"));

               var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

               var response = client.PostAsync(registerExternalUrl.ToString(), content).Result;

               // obtaining content
               var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

               if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("New user registered, with " + result.ProviderName + " account");
               }
   ```

So, here we go. Cookies are used within the whole lifecycle, from first HttpClient request to the final moment when we register a new user using *api/account/registerExternal*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to handle the cookies. The easiest way is to use the same HttpClient instance for all your requests or you can use the same CookieContainer.

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    // send request
}
```

Comment: Bernd, this is amazing!

Here's what I've done:
1. Defined CookieContainer in the MainWindow.xaml.cs and instantiated it in MainWindow_Loaded event
2. As soon as user clicks on "show external providers" button, this cookieContainer is assigned to newly created HttpClient as per your code
3. Once user selects a login provider and clicks on "Login", InternetSetCookie is called to add all existing cookies to WebBrowser
4. Once authenticated, InternetGetCookieEx is used to obtain all cookies from WebBrowser
5. Those cookies are used in calls to api/Account/UserInfo and api/Account/RegisterExternal